# Elixir Phoenix and Symlinks on Windows SMB Drive

Tags: windows, networking, phoenix-framework, smb, nas

So I have an interesting issue that I just can't figure out why I'm getting this and what to do.

So basically I store all my development projects on my Synology NAS for local access between my various devices. There has never been a problem with this until I started playing around with Elixir and more importantly Phoenix. The issue I am getting is when running `mix phx.server`. I get the following

```
[warn] Phoenix is unable to create symlinks. Phoenix' code reloader will run considerably faster if symlinks are allowed. On Windows, the lack of symlinks may even cause empty assets to be served. Luckily, you can address this issue by starting your Windows terminal at least once with "Run as Administrator" and then running your Phoenix application.
[info] Running DiscussWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.7.0 at 0.0.0.0:4000 (http)
[error] Could not start node watcher because script "z:/elHP/assets/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" does not exist. Your Phoenix application is still running, however assets won't be compiled. You may fix this by running "cd assets && npm install".
[info] Access DiscussWeb.Endpoint at http://localhost:4000
```

So I tried as it stated and ran it in CMD as admin but to no avail. After some further inspection I tried to create the symlinks manually but every time I tried I would get a `Access is denied.` error (yes this is elevated CMD).

```
c:\> mklink "z:\elHP\deps\phoenix" "z:\elHP\assets\node_modules\phoenix"
Access is denied.
```

So I believe it is something to do with the fact that the symlinks are trying to be created on the NAS because if I move the project and host it locally it will work. Now I know what you're thinking. Yes, I could just store them locally on my PC but I like to have them available between PCs without having to transfer files or rely on git etc. (i.e. offline access), not to mention that the NAS has a full backup routine.

What I have tried:

- Setting guest read write access on the SMB share
- Adding to /etc/samba/smb.conf on my Synology NAS:

```
    [global]
    unix extensions = no

    [share]
    follow symlinks = yes
    wide links = yes
```

- Extra logging on SMB to see what is happening when I try it (nothing extra logged)
- Creating a symbolic link from my MAC (works)
- Setting all of `fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation` to enabled

At the moment I am stuck and unsure of what to try next, or even if it is possible. Considering just using NFS instead but will I face the same issues with SMB?

P.S I faced a similar issue with Python venvs a while ago, just a straight-up `Access is denied.` error and just gave up and moved just the venv locally and kept the bulk of the code on the NAS. (This actually ended up beingthe best solution for that because the environments of each device on my network clashed etc.)

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should move to superuser.com